# How to disable Up/Down keys from scrolling through method overload in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio 2010 C++/C# (And pretty much every version of VS), the Up/Down arrow keys will scroll through tooltip method overloads when the tooltip is active (Either by typing a method name or by pressing Ctrl+Shift+Space while inside a method).

Is there any way to disable this feature? I constantly get hung up while trying to navigate a file with the keyboard when these tooltips appear. If there was a way to use Ctrl+Up/Down to scroll method overloads instead, that would be great, but disabling the feature entirely would be enough.

I just want my text editor to let me navigate and edit text and stop hijacking my arrow keys. Any ideas?

Comment: Mega +1: this hits me all the time too...

Comment: Real Programmers *never* press the ESC key, Chunk Norris never had to escape from an editor either.  Tools + Options, Text Editor, All Languages, untick the Statement Completion options.  Notepad can do it too.

Answer (score 5):

This may be a Resharper thing. Setting this option from "Arrow keys" to "Show Parameter Info" gave me back my arrow keys:

[image: Disabling arrow keys on yellow tooltips in Resharper in Visual Studio]

Comment: Thank you, couldn't figure out why/how it was disabled.

Comment: This maybe used to be (just) a R# thing, but as of VS2015, and possibly earlier, it is now a VS thing too. And R# will do it too in its completion lists even if you disable it for parameter info as shown here. The only "solution" I've found is to adjust the autopopup settings to make VS/R# less aggressive about showing intellisense and completion lists in the first place. See HansPassant's comment with the question for how to do this in VS. In R# 9, look at Environment > IntelliSense > AutoPopup > [language of your choice].

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking for a solution for VSCode: Open the keyboard shortcuts through `File` → `Preferences` → `Keyboard Shortcuts`, select the shortcuts `showNextParameterHint` and `showPrevParameterHint` with the shortcut `UpArrow` and `DownArrow` there and delete them by pressing the `Delete` key.